# Ruby array equality

Tags: ruby, arrays, equals

I have an array of arrays, called `guid_pairs`:

```
[['a','b','c'],['c','g'],['z','f','b']]
```

I also have an array, called `array_to_check`:

```
['c','a','b']
```

How can I determine if the array `guid_pairs` has an element that is equal to `array_to_check`. Equality should not consider the position of the array elements.

In this example, the check should return `true` because `guid_pairs` contains the element `['a','b','c']`, which matches `['c','a','b']`.

I have tried this, but it seems to always return `false` even when it should return `true`:

```
guid_pairs.any?{|pair| pair.eql?(array_to_check)}
```

I am using Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: It sounds like you're using the wrong data structure. Consider using [sets](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/index.html) instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a [set class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/classes/Set.html) in the standard library and using sets nicely matches your intent:

```
require 'set'

a  = ['c','a','b']
aa = [['a','b','c'],['c','g'],['z','f','b']]

find_this = Set.new(a)
the_match = aa.find { |x| find_this == Set.new(x) }
```

That will leave the matching element element of `aa` in `the_match`. If you're only interested in existence then you can simply check the truthiness of `the_match`; or use [`any?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001500) (thanks for the reminder Michael Kohl, I often forget about some of the things in Enumerable):

```
aa.any? { |x| find_this == Set.new(x) }
```

No tricks, no magic, and using Set makes it clear that you are, in fact, comparing the arrays as sets.

---

BTW, your attempted solution:

```
guid_pairs.any? { |pair| pair.eql?(array_to_check) }
```

doesn't work because arrays compare element-by-element in order so two arrays are equal if and only if they have equal elements in the same order. The [documentation for `eql?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000216) could be clearer:

> Returns true if self and other are the same object, or are both arrays with the same content.

But the [`==` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000215) is nice and clear:

> Two arrays are equal if they contain the same number of elements and if each element is equal to (according to Object.==) the corresponding element in the other array.

We can look to [Object#eql?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001011) for some clarification though:

> The eql? method returns true if obj and anObject have the same value. Used by Hash to test members for equality. For objects of class Object, eql? is synonymous with ==. Subclasses normally continue this tradition, but there are exceptions.

So `==` and `eql?` should behave the same way unless there is a good reason for them to be different.

Comment: You could use `any?` instead of `find` if you only care about truthiness. +1 btw, as I also prefer sets for this purpose.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for the reminder. I like the expressiveness of using Set for this sort thing, say what you mean and all that.

Answer (score 5):

To see if two arrays contain the same elements, regardless of order, you can use the XOR (exclusive or) operation. It will return an array which contains only elements that are in one array and not the other. If the length of the XOR is zero then the input arrays contain the same elements.

```
def xor(a, b)
  (a | b) - (a & b)
end

guid_pairs.any? { |pair| xor(pair, array_to_check).length != 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to sort the arrays before comparing (or even during comparing):

```
guid_pairs.any?{|pair| pair.sort.eql?(array_to_check.sort)}
```

Note that this may not be an optimal solution - it would be more appropriate to have your arrays sorted (nevertheless they are sets in your use case).

Answer (score 1):

for equality of two arrays A and B i normally use:

```
if(((A-B) + (B-A)).blank?)
    puts "equal"
else
    "unequal"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
sorted_array_to_check = array_to_check.sort
guid_pairs.any?{|pair| pair.sort.eql?(sorted_array_to_check)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three solutions:

```
class Array
  def check1 other; other.any?{|e| self - e == e - self} end
  def check2 other; other.any?{|e| self | e == self and e | self == e} end
  def check3 other; other.any?{|e| self & e == self and e & self == e} end
end
array_to_check.check1(guid_pairs) # => true
array_to_check.check2(guid_pairs) # => true
array_to_check.check3(guid_pairs) # => true
```

Without defining a method (following Josha's suggestion):

```
  array_to_check.instance_eval{guid_pairs.any?{|e| self - e == e - self}} # => true
  array_to_check.instance_eval{guid_pairs.any?{|e| self | e == self and e | self == e}} # => true
  array_to_check.instance_eval{guid_pairs.any?{|e| self & e == self and e & self == e}} # => true
```

Comment: I would avoid monkey patching Array just for one use case.

Comment: @Joshua I modified my answer.